# Change running process owner C#

Tags: c#, windows, process

Is it possible to change the owner of a process that has already been started, ideally using `C#/PInvoke` if necessary?

It looks as if `SetSecurityInfo` would allow me to do so, however every call to the function returns error `code 1307`:

> ERROR_INVALID_OWNER
>
> ```
> 1307 (0x51B)
>
> This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.
> ```

I'm not sure why I am receiving this as both accounts *original and new owner* are administrator accounts. UAC is disabled.

My Google adventures led me to believe I needed to `SetPrivileges`, but this didn't seem to change anything. Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
SecurityIdentifier userSid = getUserSid("Test");

Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
IntPtr procHandle = proc.Handle;

byte[] bytes = new byte[userSid.BinaryLength];
userSid.GetBinaryForm(bytes, 0);

GCHandle pinnedArray = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr pointer = pinnedArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();

SetPrivilege("SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege");
SetPrivilege("SeRestorePrivilege");

uint result = SetSecurityInfo(procHandle, SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, SECURITY_INFORMATION.Owner, pointer, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

pinnedArray.Free();
```

getUserSid():

```
private SecurityIdentifier getUserSid(string userName)
{
    // set up machine context
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

    // find a user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "Test");

    if (user != null)
    {
        return user.Sid;
    }
    return null;
}
```

SetPrivilege():

```
private static void SetPrivilege(string privilege)
{
    int i1 = 0;
    var luid = new LUID();
    var token_PRIVILEGES = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES();
    int i2 = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), 40, ref i1);
    if (i2 == 0)
        throw new Exception("OpenProcessToken For Privilege <" + privilege + "> Failed");
    i2 = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref luid);
    if (i2 == 0)
        throw new Exception("LookupPrivilegeValue For Privilege <" + privilege + "> Failed");
    token_PRIVILEGES.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    token_PRIVILEGES.Attributes = 2;
    token_PRIVILEGES.Luid = luid;
    i2 = AdjustTokenPrivileges(i1, 0, ref token_PRIVILEGES, 1024, 0, 0);
    if (i2 == 0)
        throw new Exception("AdjustTokenPrivileges For Privilege <" + privilege + "> Failed");
}
```

I have verified that the SID used is as expected during debugging. I also tried `handle.MainWindowHandle` but that actually led to error code 6 (invalid window handle). I'm not so sure about the pinnedArray code. It seems to be working as expected.

Comment: Try enabling backup privilege as well as restore privilege.  And check that the privileges are actually enabled (AdjustTokenPrivileges does not return an error code if the privilege isn't present in the token).  But it is also possible that you simply can't change the ownership of a process object.

Comment: For what purpose would this be useful?

Comment: I wonder if the process was started by the SYSTEM account if it then can be assigned to a real user.   What about impersonation at the point the process is started as an alternative ?

Comment: It seems likely that `proc.Handle` is the current process pseudohandle, which would not be valid for SetSecurityInfo.  You can get a real handle by duplicating it.  PS - you could test the pinned array code by setting the ownership of a simple object such as a file.